# Heroku with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My goal is to have a dynamic website (in PHP and MySQL) which will be used only by a few people. So my goal is to go with the cheapest solution possible.

After some research, I have decided to use Heroku to host my website and use Google Cloud SQL for Mysql (the Heroku free MySql engine is not good enough for my purpose).

How can I connect these two? Do I have to have IPv4 on my google instance?

Answer (score 3):

Create a MySQL instance and your database (if you don't already have them set up in your GCP project). Once this is done, select the '**Authorization**' tab within your MySQL instance in GCP and select '**Add network**' to add the Heroku network IP address before saving. Heroku runs on Amazon EC2 - you can find the full list containing all IP-addresses available to connect to Heroku [**here**](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json).

Please note that I'm unsure if there are any settings that you also have to configure in Heroku.

Comment: Thx, this is a good solution. For the lazy (you can change the region, this picks all "eu-" servers:

$.getJSON('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json', function(data) {
  let str = ""

  for (let i=0; i<data.prefixes.length; i++) {
   if(data.prefixes[i].region.indexOf("eu-")!=-1) str += data.prefixes[i].ip_prefix + ","
  }

  console.log(str.slice(0,-1));
});